# Using SqlDataAdapter in an ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, sqldataadapter

I'm writing an ASP.NET 2.0 page in VS2008.  In my Page_Load method I have the following:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString)) {
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdString, connection)) {
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        rowCount = adapter.Fill(table);
    }
}
```

What have I done wrong?

The first time I execute the page, it works fine (Fill returns one row).  If I run (Debug) the page a second time, I get zero rows.  Likewise if the page is running, and I modify one of the parameters in the URL so that the cmdString changes, I get zero rows.  If I make a trivial code change to force a re-compile, the page will again work.

Comment: Can you show us the command string and any parameters you are using.

Comment: select r.GUID, r.ACTION, wan.FriendlyActionName, r.EffectiveDate, P.FirstName, P.LastName, s.status, s.ITRComment, s.ManagerComment
from requests r
join status s on r.requestnum = s.requestnum
left join workflowactionnames wan on r.action = wan.action
left join profile p on p.profileuid = r.guid
where r.requestnum = <i>some integer</i>

Comment: How are you populating 'some integer'? Are you positive it contains a value on each load? The actual code would be most helpful here.

Comment: Doh!  Phaedrus is correct.  I was doing naive string manipulation instead of using SqlCommand.Parameters as I ought, and naturally I screwed it up.  Thank you sir.

Comment: Minor point: don't forget that SqlDataAdapter is an IDisposable too, so it should be wrapped in a using statement. Also, you can pass the SqlCommand to its constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `cmdString` had Page scope, and I was filling in a parameter with += instead of String.Replace or (more wisely) using a SqlParameter, so it was mangled on every attempt after the first.  I'm assuming that the web server embedded in VS keeps the page object alive even when you stop the debugger, which explains why it would only work once after each code change.

Thanks again to Phaedrus for asking: "Are you positive it contains a value on each load?"

Answer (score 0):

Have you used this in your Page_Load event?

```
 if(!Page.IsPostBack)
 {
   YourBindDateMethod();
 }
```

Comment: I must confess I do not quite understand this.  Is YourBindDate a .NET method?  What should it do?

Comment: Basically, YourBindDataMethod() is what Ricardo has written inside of his if statement.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the code above is running in the Page_Load event... and it runs only the first time the page loads... do you have the above code inside an statement like this?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdString, connection))
            {
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                rowCount = adapter.Fill(table);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is in the Page_Load event.  I tried adding that line, and the results are the same.  The code does run every time the page loads, but on every load subsequent to the first, zero rows are returned from Fill.

Comment: Exactly... so you need to move it outside the if(!IsPostBack) statement... that way your code will run every time the form loads. Right now it only runs the first time the form loads, that is why you don't get any data the next time the page loads.